# What is the best way to let a user know that another user is working on the same item?

Tags: design-patterns

At my company we have an admin tool, where users can create and edit surveys.

But we have a few problems with users working on the same items which in a lot of cases has lead to data getting lost or corrupted because someone else save stuff.

Is there a good way to let users know that someone else is currently working on a specific item?

**Solutions I have thought of:**

- Showing a info box with a warning letting the user know someone else is currently editing this item.
- Preventing a user from working on item that is currently being worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start as small as possible in your case, meaning to use the least amount of resources.

Start with the visual notification that the survey is already being edited by someone else.

If you still lose data because people ignore this or maybe don't see it you can work your way up till you "lock" the survey until the other person is finished editing so only one person can work on it at a time.